# How to create columns with margins between the columns using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m creating a page with Bootstrap and I need to make 4 columns leaving a space between each column of 5px!

[image]

I followed this tutorial ( http://andre-abt.com/2013/11/26/how-to-use-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system-with-column-margins/
). But for me doesn't work fine because if a put a link inside of the column to wrap all column is also possible make click outside  of the column. (It's possible click in that 5px of margin).

[image]

jsfiddle.net/andresgl/2f7Lhmwd/ (Conferences, Summits, Events)

I hope some can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's because if the absolute position `.txt-main-menu > a` element inside the col, not the custom bootstrap gutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overcomplicated example for what you want to achieve, but if you want to keep it as it is add

```
.item-menu {    
    position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2f7Lhmwd/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
a{ margin:0;padding:0; }
```

This will remove all padding and margins from the anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user3428341. I tried that but doesn't work :( http://i.imgur.com/qLy2kJc.png?1 Thank you!